# Text Overlay on Images on Responsive Grid using HTML/CCS?

Tags: css

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I have a responsive grid of images and wish to have a mouseover. The problem is most the methods I have seen need an image to have a defined width/height.

In my instance, its not defined so that it is responsive at certain breaks.

I want to achieve this:

[Text Overlay Example (The centred white box with text)](http://s23.postimg.org/o44sx043f/Screen_Shot_2015_03_11_at_14_52_22.png)

My current HTML code is:

```
    <table id="Table_01" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/home_grid_01.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
        <td rowspan="5">
            <img src="images/home_grid_02.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/home_grid_03.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
        <td rowspan="5">
            <img src="images/home_grid_04.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/home_grid_05.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/home_grid_06.png" walt="" class="maingrid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/home_grid_07.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/home_grid_08.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/home_grid_09.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/home_grid_10.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/home_grid_11.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/home_grid_12.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/home_grid_13.png" alt="" class="maingrid"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS is:

```
img.maingrid {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}

tr.maingrid {

}

td.maingrid {

}

#Table_01 {
    width:960px;
    height:500px;
    line-height: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px){
    #Table_01 {
        width:754px;
        height:auto;
    }
}

    @media only screen and (max-width: 754px){
    #Table_01 {
        width:440px;
        height:auto;
    }
}
```

Is it possible with just HTML/CSS?

The styling of the text I can do. I just can't achieve the overlay box with text inside centred in the middle like the image provided.

Comment: Where is the 'overlay' in your HTML?

Comment: Of cousre, but please show your working code with overlay

Comment: I don't have it yet. What I tired was to play with http://jsfiddle.net/dYxYs/ and use something like that but I don't know how to incorporate it due to the images I'm working with being responsive in situ and of varying sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the simplest method is to use an absolutely positioned overlay element

Media queries would still be required to adjust sizes but...for example:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
#Table_01 {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}
td {
  position: relative;
}

 td:hover .overlay {
 display:block; 
 }

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<table id="Table_01" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-100-100-7.jpg" alt="" class="maingrid" />
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="5">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-100-100-7.jpg" alt="" class="maingrid" />
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-100-100-7.jpg" alt="" class="maingrid" />
    </td>
    <td rowspan="5">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-100-100-7.jpg" alt="" class="maingrid" />
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-100-100-7.jpg" alt="" class="maingrid" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paulie_D. How would this be expanded for an overlay/mouseover? I only require the text to be displayed (refer to image) when mouseover.

Comment: Added a hover functionality to demo.